# How to intregate django rest-framework with frontend?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I am building Django Web Application.
I am using rest-framework but i am so confused.

Like this method I am getting the data but how will I render the data in html file

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([JWTAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def homeapi(request):
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        print(data)
        
        # Dummy student data (replace this with your logic to fetch real data from a database)
        dummy_students = [
            {'id': 1, 'name': 'Alice', 'age': 20, 'grade': 'A'},
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 22, 'grade': 'B'},
            {'id': 3, 'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 21, 'grade': 'C'},
            # Add more students as needed
        ]

        # Return student details as JSON response
        return JsonResponse({'students': dummy_students})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=400)
```

I am expecting that first I am requesting the data by this API after getting the data I want to show it to the user how will i do that.

Comment: Could you specify exactly what is confusing you? Normally, you don't do: `data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))`. This is done by serializers. They act like django forms, validating what the user sends and giving us python native objects to work with. Have a look at [DRF Filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters)

Comment: actually i am working with jwt token.I donot understand how will i intregrated django rest framework jwt token with frontend